# Simple Calculator in Bison

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am new to parsing. Following is a code snippet for a parser in Bison :

**Parser.y**:

```
%{ 
#include <stdio.h> 
%}
/* declare tokens */ 
%token NUMBER 
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV ABS 
%token EOL

%%

calclist: /* nothing */  
| calclist exp EOL { printf("= %d\n", $1); } 
;
exp: factor       
| exp ADD factor { $$ = $1 + $3; } 
| exp SUB factor { $$ = $1 - $3; } 
;
factor: term 
| factor MUL term { $$ = $1 * $3; } 
| factor DIV term { $$ = $1 / $3; } 
;
term: NUMBER 
| ABS term   { $$ = $2 >= 0? $2 : - $2; } 
; 

%% 

main(int argc, char **argv) 
{  yyparse(); 
}
yyerror(char *s) 
{  fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s); 
}
```

I am struggling to understand how the input string `10 - 3 * 2 + 6` will be parsed/processed adhering to the operator precedence. Can anyone please describe the parsing mechanism step-by-step ? For e.g.

```
Step1: 10 is read and token NUMBER is returned
Step2: etc....
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

bison parsers will happily tell you exactly what they are doing if you ask them to, by using bison's [trace facility](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing).

To get the following trace, I used your input file with minimal changes:

- I fixed the prototypes with no return value (`main` and `yyerror`) and added forward declarations of `yylex` and `yyerror`.
- I fixed the `printf` in `calclist` to print the value of the expression (`$2`) rather than the calclist itself, which has no value.
- I changed the single character tokens (`ADD`, `SUB`, etc.) to the actual single characters (`'+'`, `-`, etc.) in order to simplify the scanner
- I added a trivial lexer.
- Finally, I enabled tracing by adding `yydebug = 1;` to the `main` function and invoking bison with the `-t` flag.

The result, using the expression you provide, is below. To understand the state transitions, you will want to print out the state transition table. Use the `-v` option to bison.

```
$ ./trace <<< '10 - 3 * 2 + 6'
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 13):
-> $$ = nterm calclist ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 1
Reading a token: Next token is token NUMBER ()
Shifting token NUMBER ()
Entering state 3
Reducing stack by rule 10 (line 22):
   $1 = token NUMBER ()
-> $$ = nterm term ()
Stack now 0 1
Entering state 9
Reducing stack by rule 7 (line 19):
   $1 = nterm term ()
-> $$ = nterm factor ()
Stack now 0 1
Entering state 8
Reading a token: Next token is token '-' ()
Reducing stack by rule 4 (line 16):
   $1 = nterm factor ()
-> $$ = nterm exp ()
Stack now 0 1
Entering state 7
Next token is token '-' ()
Shifting token '-' ()
Entering state 14
Reading a token: Next token is token NUMBER ()
Shifting token NUMBER ()
Entering state 3
Reducing stack by rule 10 (line 22):
   $1 = token NUMBER ()
-> $$ = nterm term ()
Stack now 0 1 7 14
Entering state 9
Reducing stack by rule 7 (line 19):
   $1 = nterm term ()
-> $$ = nterm factor ()
Stack now 0 1 7 14
Entering state 18
Reading a token: Next token is token '*' ()
Shifting token '*' ()
Entering state 15
Reading a token: Next token is token NUMBER ()
Shifting token NUMBER ()
Entering state 3
Reducing stack by rule 10 (line 22):
   $1 = token NUMBER ()
-> $$ = nterm term ()
Stack now 0 1 7 14 18 15
Entering state 19
Reducing stack by rule 8 (line 20):
   $1 = nterm factor ()
   $2 = token '*' ()
   $3 = nterm term ()
-> $$ = nterm factor ()
Stack now 0 1 7 14
Entering state 18
Reading a token: Next token is token '+' ()
Reducing stack by rule 6 (line 18):
   $1 = nterm exp ()
   $2 = token '-' ()
   $3 = nterm factor ()
-> $$ = nterm exp ()
Stack now 0 1
Entering state 7
Next token is token '+' ()
Shifting token '+' ()
Entering state 13
Reading a token: Next token is token NUMBER ()
Shifting token NUMBER ()
Entering state 3
Reducing stack by rule 10 (line 22):
   $1 = token NUMBER ()
-> $$ = nterm term ()
Stack now 0 1 7 13
Entering state 9
Reducing stack by rule 7 (line 19):
   $1 = nterm term ()
-> $$ = nterm factor ()
Stack now 0 1 7 13
Entering state 17
Reading a token: Next token is token '\n' ()
Reducing stack by rule 5 (line 17):
   $1 = nterm exp ()
   $2 = token '+' ()
   $3 = nterm factor ()
-> $$ = nterm exp ()
Stack now 0 1
Entering state 7
Next token is token '\n' ()
Shifting token '\n' ()
Entering state 12
Reducing stack by rule 3 (line 15):
   $1 = nterm calclist ()
   $2 = nterm exp ()
   $3 = token '\n' ()
= 10
-> $$ = nterm calclist ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 1
Reading a token: Now at end of input.
Shifting token $end ()
Entering state 2
Stack now 0 1 2
Cleanup: popping token $end ()
Cleanup: popping nterm calclist ()
```

Comment: a question - after token **10** is read from the input and gets reduced to `NUMBER --> term --> factor` ,why doesn't it get further reduced to `exp` by the rule `exp: factor` (rule 7). Instead it goes on to read the next token (i.e " **-** " ) ?

Comment: @Raj: It does reduce using rule 7. That's clear in the trace.